# opencv extracting all horizontal and vertical lines separately using morphological operation

Tags: c++, opencv, extract

I am new to opencv. I am working with opencv and C++ on visual studio 2013. I have a task to extract all horizontal and vertical lines of a document containing a table separately and use that to extract the cells present in the table.

I can only use morphological operation to achieve that.

Can anyone suggest the procedure to achieve that?

Here is a sample document.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Are you allowed to use Hough? http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

Comment: No, houghlines are also not allowed .
Thanks for the reply

Comment: What's the document like? Could you snip an image of it?

Comment: any document image, for sample you can look at  this URL http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/images/table2.gif

Answer (score 2):

[image][image]Finally got the output.
Look at the code.

```
string src = "d://sabari//23.jpg";
Mat im = imread(src);
Mat gray;


if (im.channels() == 3)
{
    cvtColor(im, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
}
else
{
    gray = im;
}

adaptiveThreshold(~gray, gray, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 15, -2);
Mat vertical = gray.clone();
int horizontalsize = gray.cols / 30;

Mat structure = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(horizontalsize,1));

erode(gray, gray,structure, Point(-1, -1));
dilate(gray, gray,structure, Point(-1, -1));

imshow("ans", gray);
imwrite("d://out2.jpg", gray);

int verticalsize = vertical.rows / 30;

Mat verticalStructure = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size( 1,verticalsize));

erode(vertical, vertical, verticalStructure, Point(-1, -1));
dilate(vertical, vertical, verticalStructure, Point(-1, -1));

imshow("ans1", vertical);
imwrite("d://out3.jpg", vertical);
```

Comment: I got horizontal line separately and vertical lines separately. As i used line as my structuring element, it is able to delete rest elements and i am left with only lines. When i need vertical lines i use structure element "verticalStructure" as mentioned in the code.

Comment: Well done, if you show an output image it will be even more helpful to people reading this post in the future.